# Pygame will only play some .wav files

Tags: python-2.7, audio, pygame, raspberry-pi3

I am currently trying to programme some Christmas lights using the GPIO pins on the raspberry pi 3. and the lights work, so i decided to put some Christmas music to it as well. when using Pygame, Python won't let me use .mp3 files, and it only lets me play certain .wav files, so when i downloaded some christmas songs from http://www.thewavsite.com/christmas.htm, none of them worked. i will attach the code that i used. I hope you can be of help.

```
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()
s = pygame.mixer.Sound("all_i_want_for_christmas.wav")
s.play()
print "Happy christmas!!"
```

Comment: I checked one song using on Linux commands `file` and `ffprobe` and both show that this `.wav` uses `mp3` compression :)

Comment: rename those wav files as .mp3 and they should play fine ... mistakenly called .wav when they are really mp3 ... confirm using command line tool ... `ffprobe aaa.wav`

Comment: I have that issue too, maybe place the file in audacity and re-export it as .wav, sometimes its the wrong bit-depth and pygame refuses to open it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked one of christmas songs using on Linux commands `file` and `ffprobe` and both show that this `.wav` uses `mp3` compression :)

You will have to convert to real `wav` before you use it with `PyGame`.

---

`file` shows

```
A Christmas To Remember - Kenny Rogers & Dolly Parton.wav: 
 RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, MPEG Layer 3, mono 22050 Hz
```

`ffprobe` shows

```
Input #0, wav, from 'A Christmas To Remember - Kenny Rogers & Dolly Parton.wav':
  Duration: 00:03:39.75, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 22050 Hz, mono, s16p, 32 kb/s
```

Comment: do you know how to change a mp3 file to a wav?

Comment: I use program [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) in command line (bash) to convert audio or video but there are many other programs. BTW: Python module [MoviePy](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy) uses `ffmpeg` in background. Other modules (like [PyMedia](http://pymedia.org/tut/index.html)) can also convert media.

Comment: I downloaded ffmpeg, and i opened the terminal and typed in the following code, but all it said was bash: ffmpeg: command not found

Comment: ffmpg -i jingle_bells.mp3 jingle_bells.wav

Comment: try with standard instalator - ie. `apt` on Ubuntu. Did you run command in folder with `ffmpeg` ? If you download manually then it will not add this to `PATH` and you have to run with full path `/full/path/to/bin/ffmpeg -i jingle_bells.mp3 jingle_bells.wav`

Comment: i tried everything you said but it didn't work. so i decided to download some .wav files on my laptop and copy them across. when i copied them across, they worked, so i wondering if it was the website that had something wrong with it?

Comment: On this webside `wav` files use `mp3` compression but `PyGame` can works only with `wav` which uses standard compression. Many programs don't check file extension to recognize file type but they check few first bytes in file - so called "magic number" - and wrong extension doesn't make problem.

Comment: BTW: text `"didn't work."` is useless information (and maybe the most hated text on Stackoverflow). If you have problem then describe it, put error message, etc.

Comment: I will try not to use "didn't work" in the future, and thank you for the advice. the error the terminal gave me was    bash: ffmpeg: command not found

Comment: I also downloaded the songs on my laptop and it picked up that they were .wav files, so i converted them on a website to .mp3 files and then back to .wav file and copied them across to my raspberry pi, and they still didn't play